# Prestashop Sitemap don't reflect products I added in year 2018

Tags: prestashop, xml-sitemap

I tried re-generating `sitemap` so many times from the `Google sitemap` module in Prestashop.

But somehow it just wouldn't show the new products i have added in year 2018.

See http://dreamscaper.sg/1_en_0_sitemap.xml

If you scroll down, you can see the last item that was added is in `Nov 2017`.

```
2017-11-10T21:37:37+08:00
```

However, I have added so many more new product since then!

I suspect this caused my site ranking to drop in Google because the spiders are not seeing any new product added via the sitemap. How would I be able to fix this?

Comment: FYI, I disable cache all along. 
​​​​​​​So i doubt it is a cache problem. (i guess?)

Comment: Have you checked your permissions on the xml file ? Are you allowed to overwrite it ?